# intel_do_flush_locked failed: Cannot allocate memory VMD software

Tags: kernel

I am frequently getting:

```
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

when running VMD (X11 program) software in ubuntu 16.04. I have 8GB of RAM Ubuntu 16.04.2 What should I do?

Which Kernel version should I use?

```
uname -a
Linux saikat 4.12.0-041200-generic #201707022031 SMP Mon Jul 3 00:32:52 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: From the very small amount I am able to glean from the bug reports, it seems to be a problem with the Intel graphics drivers.  There are a few reports that setting `LIBGL_DRI3_DISABLE=1` as an environment variable help the problem, and you could try this, although it is not a certain fix.